# Why "fractional" anisotropy?

Tags: measurement, neuroimaging, fmri

Why is [Fractional Anisotropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_anisotropy) (FA), a measure in diffusion tensor imaging, called "fractional"? I'd have thought "local", i.e. voxel-wise, would have been the correct way to qualify the anisotropy that is calculated from the tensor model, so why fractional?

Comment: I am not completely fresh on the subject, but from what I recall when studying the subject, FA measurements are meant to represent not an absolute signal, but a radio between axial and radial diffusion.

Comment: Makes sense! :)

Answer (score 3):

Like *lea*'s comment indicated, FA is called "fractional" anisotropy simply because it's the degree of anisotropic diffusion, i.e., a ratio (Soares, Marques, Alves and Sousa, 2013).

> Fractional Anisotropy is **a normalized measure of the fraction of the tensor's magnitude due to anisotropic diffusion**, corresponding to the degree of anisotropic diffusion or directionality and ranges from 0 (isotropic diffusion) to 1 (anisotropic diffusion).

**References**

- [Soares, J. M., Marques, P., Alves, V., & Sousa, N. (2013). A hitchhiker’s guide to diffusion tensor imaging. Frontiers in Neuroscience, 7, 31. doi:10.3389/fnins.2013.00031](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3594764/)